# In WPF, how do I get the content of a tabItem to fill available space?

Tags: wpf, tabitem, autosize

I do not know what I am doing wrong here. In the XAML below, the Border does not fill the available space on the tabItem (just lots of whitespace). How do I fill the entire tab page?

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Plant State">
        <Border Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Your xaml works fine for me. There's a 4-pixel-or-so inner padding but that's par for the course with TabControl. Is that the "whitespace" you're talking about?

Comment: Hi Matt. So your TabItem is filled with a red rectangle? Not so for me. Maybe it's a problem with the overall template I am applying. Will try the same thing in a small/clean WPF app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of Matt Hamilton. This actually works fine if you are using a regular TabControl (default Template).

I am using a xaml "theme" that alters the default control template. That is causing the layout to fail, so I will have to investigate and figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @willem: ... so what was the problem here?

Comment: Answer is also @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069462/wpf-tabitem-content-alignment-is-always-centered