# WPF label horizontal content alignment with flexibel width

Tags: wpf, width, tabcontrol, text-alignment, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` with some `TabItems`.

The Header of the `TabItems` consists of a `UserControl` with a `label` and a `button`.
For this i followed this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem).

The horizontal alignment of the `label` does not work because the width is set to auto.
This causes the text to be centred and the `buttons` are not all the way to the right where they should be.

But I need the width to be flexible so that no long text is cut off.

This is with the width set to auto and this is with a fixed width.

[image]
[image]

I want it to look like the picture with the fixed width but with a flexible width depending on the length of the labels.

Edit: I don´t use a theme like in the suggestion brought up in the comments.

This is my XAML code:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CSM.UserControls.CloseableHeaderUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="81" Margin="0" Height="20.5" >
    <Grid Margin="0,4,0,0">
        <Button Content="X" Name="bClose" FontFamily="Courier" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="14"  ToolTip="Close" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-4,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="TabItem" Name="lTabTitle" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="auto" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-4"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF TabItem Content alignment is always centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069462/wpf-tabitem-content-alignment-is-always-centered)

Comment: @Ash sadly this doesn´t help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DockPanel with LastChildFill:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" ... />
  <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" ... />      
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: This does not work quite right. The text is aligned on the right side despite horizontal alignment set to left: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hEMq.png)

Comment: You need to set alignment:

<Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0" ... />

Comment: when I add this, nothing changes from the appearance either.
Except when I set the width from auto to a fixed size

Comment: You don't need to set width for Label. Let the DockPanel manage it.